# file:// URL that would work the same on Mac and PC (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to create a "launch" page that is just a simple HTML page with a link of my bookmarks that I can edit myself. I want this page to come up when I open a new tab in Google Chrome.  (In other words, I'm trying to create a custom HTML page that would automatically load in new Chrome tabs.)

I am using "New Tab Redirect" extension in Google Chrome to load this file when I open a new tab.  The challenge is using a file:// URLs that would work on both Macs and PCs.

I have two laptops, one is Mac and the other is PC.

`file:///tmp/bookmarks.html` works on macos when I put my bookmarks in /tmp/bookmarks.html, but it doesn't work on PC. (I tried creating 'c:\tmp\bookmarks.html` on the PC but Chrome doesn't pick it up.)

`file://C:/tmp/bookmarks.html` works on PC but doesn't work on macos (I tried creating `/C:/` and linking from `tmp` in there to `/tmp` but no dice).

Is there any `file://` URL that would work on both systems?

P.S. Earlier, I tried using an http:// URL (running a local web server to share the bookmarks.html) but it was noticeably slow to load compared to loading a file:// resource

Comment: For windows, if you set the `tmp` in `tmp/bookmarks.html` as a share, then `file://///localhost/tmp/bookmarks.html` should work. Not sure about the mac side of the equation.

Comment: By "not sure" I meant I don't know exactly how to implement it, but I do expect e.g. setting up a SMB share in the same manner should work. Using "localhost" should resolve the same way to the same path on both machines. It may also be possible to not prepend the file protocol, but that depends on chrome. Not that you aren't actually grabbing from the network, just exposing the directory tree to the network interface.

Comment: Understood, thank you, @Yorik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood the question. OP can use the chrome-extension:// URL approach.

According to [the wiki](https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect/wiki), your install paths are here:

Windows: `C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna\`

Mac: `Macintosh HD\Users\**username**\Library\Application Support\Google\Chrome\Default\Extensions\icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna\`

You can place the file there for it to appear in both places.

`chrome-extension://icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/`

Just to drive the point home, `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna\custom-html.html` can be reached at `chrome-extension://icpjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/custom-html.html`

---

old answer:
As I understand it, you're trying to create the anchor in your custom HTML document?

You could write the document for Mac and then have a script rewrite the prefix:

```
// check if we are using Windows -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1){

  // loop over all the anchors
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a")).forEach((a) => {

    // if it starts with file
    if (a.href.indexOf("file:///" == 0)) { 
      
      // do the actual replace (adjust as needed)
      a.href = a.href.replace("file:///", "file://C:/"); 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a custom HTML document that will load when I open a new tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: The file URL should link _to_ this document or is it _inside_ the document?

Comment: The file URL should link _to_ this document.  That's how Chrome knows where to find the document.

Comment: I realize this is late, but: the github documentation shows where the plugin installs to. Can you use the chrome-extension:// approach? I set my redirect page to chrome-extension://<random>/options.html and it took me to that page. Maybe you already figured that out!

Comment: My New Tab Redirect options file on the Mac is in "Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna/3.1.5_0/options.html"  (I use profiles on this system).  Won't this leave me chasing the New Tab Redirect version number?

Comment: The link to https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect/wiki was very helpful! Thank you! I tried making my own new tab override extension patterned on https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/override/blank_ntp/ but it doesn't show up on the other computer... I guess local extensions aren't synced. Only ones hosted on Google Chrome Web Store.

Comment: An update on this: I found that Vimium (another extension) is not allowed to run on the HTML page loaded into the new tab loaded by new extension.  I also found out that this file:// URL works on both platforms:  `file:///C%3A/tmp/bookmarks.html` (I have to URL-encode the colon in "C:" and create a "/C:/tmp" on the Mac) but Chrome refuses to load my newtab override extension if I set newtab override to it. So close!

Comment: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/2167

Comment: I ended up using Vimium's "New tab URL" setting with the value of `file:///C%3A/tmp/bookmarks.html` to override the Chrome new tab value.